# Shell navigation in .NET MAUI to a page with Bottom Tabs

Tags: maui, .net-maui

During a login flow, the login page does not normally have bottom tabs which constitute the main flow of the app.

AppShell.xaml

```
 <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="Home"
             Icon="home.png" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Articles"
                          Icon="articles.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ArticlesPage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

So I am attempting to navigate from the login page, given login successful, to the HomePage which is part of a TabBar in Shell. Problem is Shell then navigates to the HomePage as if it is a page on its own, without the TabBar.
I am assuming that the answer lies in navigating to the TabBar section itself, I don't know.

Comment: Have you considered including the login page as a page in your TabBar as well, and just use visibility to control which tabs are shown? (If there's only one tab visible, the shell automatically hides the tab title.)

Comment: I had not thought of that. Let me try that out

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your requirement.

---

##### Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `AppShell` as `MainPage` in `App`.
2. Place Two `Tabbar` in AppShell , and place `LoginPage` first then `HomePage`, and set  different `Route` for the two `Tabbar`.

   ```
   <TabBar Route="Login">
     <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
   </TabBar>

   <TabBar Route="Home">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" Icon="home.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Articles" Icon="articles.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ArticlesPage}" />
   </TabBar>
   ```
3. Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Home");` when login in , Call `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Login");` when login out .

##### Don't Include LoginPage into AppShell

1. Set `LoginPage` as `MainPage` in `App` at first.
2. Call `MainPage = new AppShell();` When login in , Call `MainPage = new LoginPage();` when login out .

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ColeX's answer, it will still work perfectly without the `TabBar` control.

```
 <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LoginPage}"
               Route="LoginPage"/>

 <TabBar Route="Home">
     <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="HomePage" Icon="home.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
     <ShellContent Title="Articles" Route="ArticlesPage" Icon="articles.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ArticlesPage}"/>
 </TabBar>
```

---

**Login Button event-handler in LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ApiHelper is a static class with methods that communicate with an API.
    var response = await ApiHelper.Login(EntEmail.Text, EntPassword.Text);

    if (response)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//HomePage");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("", "Operation failed", "Cancel");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** EntEmail and EntPassword are the names of two Entry controls in LoginPage.xaml.