# .NET MAUI Shell navigation - Is there any way to push a tabbed page onto current page?

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

I can set the route of a TabBar in Appshell similar to this one,
[Shell navigation in .NET MAUI to a page with Bottom Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375482/shell-navigation-in-net-maui-to-a-page-with-bottom-tabs)
It seems that I can only access these tabbed pages by calling route "//OverLay" and I will lose the stack when I call the route.

AppShell.xmal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1">


    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage"/>

    <TabBar Title="Annotation" Route="Annotation">

    <Tab Title="Shape">
        <ShellContent Title="ShapePage"
                        Route="ShapePage"
                        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:ShapePage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Callout">
        <ShellContent Title="CalloutPage"
                        Route="CalloutPage"
                        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:CalloutPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Sign">
        <ShellContent Title="SignPage"
                        Route="SignPage"
                        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SignPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="Go to Tabbed Annotation" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Annotation");
}
```

Comment: `but I will lose the stack when I call the route`  How did you lose stack? Could you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: Original question modified. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: I did a test based on your code, we could switch between these pages normally. I still don't understand what you mean by words `I will lose the stack when I call the route`. How did you call the route? If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thank you! I update the original question again. Also uploaded it to github. https://github.com/whichone/MauiApp1.App  I need the tabbed page to be pushed on top of the main page and go back to the main page with parameters.

Comment: Your code should not have been uploaded completely, at least I didn't find the `.sln`  file.

Comment: I saved it directly from VS and don't know why the solution file wasn't included but you should be able to open the project file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code while logging out:

```
private  async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
}
```